# URL to open plunker running the script

Tags: plunker

I'm trying to use plunker it for oauth authentication. To do so, I need a url that my script can GET which will give a plunker page running my script.

In JSFiddle, I use https://fiddle.jshell.net/my_name/fiddle_id/show/

**is there a way to do that in plunker?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you import dependencies from your other plunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957246/can-you-import-dependencies-from-your-other-plunks)

Answer (score 0):

Saved Plunks are available at `http(s)://run.plnkr.co/plunk/{plunkId}/*`. The dynamic previews that are generated as you edit your code are at `http(s)://run.plnkr.co/preview/{previewId}/*` but these urls expire after a short period of time.